# Show that T2-space is preserved by continuous map.

Tags: general-topology

> Let (X,$\tau$) and (Y,$\tau_1$) be topological spaces and f : (X,$\tau$)$\rightarrow$(Y,$\tau_1$) a continuous
>   map. If f is one-to-one, prove that (Y,$\tau_1$) is Hausdorff implies that (X,$\tau$) is Hausdorff.

I already proved that T1 is preserved by continuous map, but I don't know how to do with T2. Please give me some idea.

Comment: This is not preservation. Preservation would be the other implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be distinct points in $X$ then since $f$ is one to one then $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are distinct points. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff we can find neighbourhoods that separate these two points. Then the preimages of these neighbourhoods are disjoint  and open since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Where is the one-to-one condition comes into play?

Comment: To separate $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ we need injectivity otherwise they may map to the same point.